# python discord bot send message without any activity

Tags: python, discord

I am having a hard time just sending a message without anything happening with python. I have searched and searched and the only thing I can find is python code that does something when there is activity in discord (i.e. replies to messages, or deletes offensive material) I can get all of that to work just fine. but I cannot figure out for the life of me on how to send a message in general.

I dont have code because I do not see a way to do this. if someone could just point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated

Comment: Chat bots are incredibly event driven. Something happens -> bot reacts. If you want the bot to continuously send messages you can subscribe on the `on_ready` event (bot comes online), put a `while` loop there with some `asyncio.sleep` and put the logic of your bot sending messages there.

Comment: This does not work because how do you send the message in discord? the examples do not provide a way to post stuff in a certain channel during on_ready

Comment: You can get a channel object in `on_ready` with [e.g. this method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel).

Comment: but you cannot send a message. From what I understand, 'client.send_mesage' was replaced with 'client.send' but these do not work

Comment: Your link provided me with the FAQ. which answered my questions. I am now ok. here is the link for the next person
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel